# Piecewise linear regression notation

Tags: regression, linear-model, linear

I want to write out the following regression in $X\beta + \epsilon$ form.

$Y = \begin{cases}
          \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2  &\text{if high school education}\\
          (\beta_0 + \beta_3) + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 &\text{if college degree}                
    \end{cases}$

If I were to write it out as I matrix, I'd just use two dummy variables but I'm not sure what notation is proper for this question. (Like you'd just have to add the $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ together by hand

Comment: Let $x_3=1$ if college degree, otherwise $0$.  Then $Y=x^T\beta$.

Comment: Yeah that's what I went with, feels good getting some validation though. Thank you!